# How to encrypt a large number of existing files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have too many files to encrypt manually in the console - is there an awscli command I can run to encrypt all files in a bucket with SSE-S3?

Comment: There are numerous encryption options for objects in S3. Are you referring to the basic SSE-S3 option?

Comment: Yes I am, edited

Answer (score 2):

To encrypt an existing S3 object using Server-Side Encryption ([SSE-S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html)), copy the file over itself, adding the encryption option `--sse AES256`. For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/cat.jpg s3://mybucket/cat.jpg --sse AES256
```

For large numbers of objects, you will want to automate this, perhaps [using S3 Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/encrypting-objects-with-amazon-s3-batch-operations/).